# Complexity of a recursive bignum multiplication algorithm

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, recursion

We have started learning about analysis of recursive algorithms and I got the gist of it. However there are some questions, like the one I'm going to post, that confuse me a little.

#### The exercise

> Consider the problem of multiplying two big integers, i.e. integers represented by a large number of bits that cannot be handled directly by the ALU of a single CPU. This type of multiplication has applications in data security where big integers are used in encryption schemes. The elementary-school algorithm for multiplying two n-bit integers has a complexity of . To improve this complexity, let x and y be the two n-bit integers, and use the following algorithm
>
> ```
> Recursive-Multiply(x,y)
>   Write  x = x1 * 2^(n/2)+x0  //x1 and x0 are high order and low order n/2 bits
>        y = y1 * 2^(n/2)+y0//y1 and y0  are high order and low order n/2 bits
>   Compute x1+x0  and y1+y0
>   p = Recursive-Multiply (x1+x0,y1+y0)
>   x1y1 = Recursive-Multiply (x1,y1)
>   x0y0 = Recursive-Multiply (x0,y0)
>   Return  x1y1*2^n + (p-x1y1-x0y0)*2^(n/2)+x0y0
> ```
>
> (a) Explain how the above algorithm works and provides the correct answer.
>
> (b) Write a recurrence relation for the number of basic operations for the above algorithm.
>
> (c) Solve the recurrence relation and show that its complexity is $O(n^{\lg 3})$

#### My conjecture

1. Since the method is being called three times, the complexity is going to be $3C(n/2) + n/2$.

#### My questions

1. What do they mean by hi-lo order bits?
2. How can I use a recurrence relation on this if I don't know how each recursion works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is to divide each $n$-bit integer into two halves of $n/2$ bits. For example, $10100010$ would be divided into $1010$ and $0010$. Naively, we would need to multiply four such halves, but in fact there is a way to do with only three. (This is similar to matrix multiplication algorithms such as Strassen's.) The algorithm described by the exercise is known as [Karatsuba multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karatsuba_algorithm).

Regarding your other question, once you have reduced the computation of running time to a recurrence relation, you no longer need to understand anything more about the recursion in order to compute the running time - this is the main point of this abstraction.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense now. Another question: is my complexity assumption correct?

Comment: Well, $n/2$ has no meaning, since you don't know how much each operation actually costs - instead, you want $O(n)$. Other than that, it looks fine.

Comment: I saw the complexity on the page you provided. How can I do recurrence on it with c and d in the way?

Comment: Take $f(n) = cn + d$ and use $f(n) = \Theta(n)$.

Comment: Ah, ok. My professor used an instead of cn+d. Is that also ok?

Comment: You should understand what $\Theta(n)$ means. That's more important than what you professor used, and could help you answer your own question.